# Rare IE10 bug: CSS animation of background-position fails with multiple backgrounds and percentage

Tags: internet-explorer-10, css-animations, background-position, background-image

This is a very specific bug - however, I would love for someone to show me a workaround! The bug basically consists in IE10 failing to do CSS animation of `background-position` when these two conditions are met **at the same time**:

- Having multiple backgrounds
- Setting `background-position` in percent

Here's a demo, compare Chrome with IE10:

http://codepen.io/dalgard/pen/LiyIK

Comment: Using a keyword like "right" instead of a percentage gives the same result.

Comment: Oh, I should note (in case MS is reading): I first discovered the error on a quite complex page I was building, *but* in that case (not with the demo), once in every ~15 refreshes a few of the elements actually did animate like they should! So strange.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a percentage sign after the zeros.
It must be so:

```
@keyframes move {
  0% { background-position: 0%, 0%; }
  100% { background-position: 0%, 100%; }
}
```