# Background animation in IE 10 or later

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, background-position, background-size

I've been trying to animate a background in IE but the image is just still. It works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. I've tried similar setup like this [Rare IE10 bug: CSS animation of background-position fails with multiple backgrounds and percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053703/rare-ie10-bug-css-animation-of-background-position-fails-with-multiple-backgrou#new-answer)

It works there but not with my code. Does anyone know what it is that IE/Edge doesn't support? Searching reference pages got me nowhere. Code below

```css
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% { background-size: 310px 400px; }
    40% { background-size: 1450px 1900px; }
    40% { background-position: -50px -1050px; }
    60% { background-size: 1450px 1900px; }
    60% { background-position: -50px -1350px; }
    100% { background-size: 310px 400px; }
}
@keyframes move {
    0% { background-size: 310px 400px; }
    40% { background-size: 1450px 1900px; }
    40% { background-position: -50px -1050px; }
    60% { background-size: 1450px 1900px; }
    60% { background-position: -50px -1350px; }
    100% { background-size: 310px 400px; }
}

div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('2024x3008image.png');
    background-size: 310px 400px;
    background-position: top left;
    -webkit-animation: move 10s infinite;
    animation: move 10s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Found the answer eventually. Neither  IE or Edge support background-size animation (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn254934(v=vs.85).aspx ). Which is very disappointing, like IE always is.